# jQuery: for loop element attr change, all elements have last elements attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm having a bit of trouble with my for loop.  I think this should be relatively easy but for some reason I just can't figure it out!

I have a for loop, which takes list items from one list and clones them into another.  Once this is done, the new list items need a rel attribute with the `i` value.

Once the loop has completed, all of the list elements are given a rel with the final `i` value (3) - As shown below.

**STARTING HTML**

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul id="newList">

</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
for (i = 0; i < $('#list li').length; i++) {
  $('#newList').html($('#list li').clone().attr('rel', i));
}
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul id="newList">
  <li rel="0">1</li>
  <li rel="1">2</li>
  <li rel="2">3</li>
  <li rel="3">4</li>
</ul>
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul id="newList">
  <li rel="3">1</li>
  <li rel="3">2</li>
  <li rel="3">3</li>
  <li rel="3">4</li>
</ul>
```

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/dtxs4nxj/

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The important thing to realize here is that `$('#newList').html($('#list li')` is a jQuery Element Array. Since that represents the entire Array and your loop reaches it's end the last value `3` goes to all of the Elements. You should use `.each()` or `$.each()` nstead of a regular for loop in jQuery anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time through the loop, you're cloning **all** the `li`s, giving all the clones the same `rel` attribute, and putting that in the HTML of `#newList` (replacing what was put there on the previous iteration). Instead, you should clone each one separately, and append it to `#newList`.

```js
$("#list li").each(function(i) {
  $(this).clone().attr('rel', i).appendTo("#newList");
});
$("#html").text($("#newList").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul id="newList">

</ul>
<br>newList HTML:
<div id="html"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that each time the loop goes round the contents of `#newList` is replaced with clones of all the `li`'s in `#list`.  This means you are seeing the result of the final iteration of your `for` loop.

Try using `.each` instead -

```
$('#list li').each (function (index, me){
    // "index" is the index of the li and "me" is the li itself
    // "append" will add the cloned element to the end of "#newList"
    $('#newList').append(
        $(me).clone().attr('rel', index)
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the append function in `.append`.

And the `$('#list li')` will select the 4 itens in `ul` list.

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

That's why I got the `first-child` : 
`$('#list li:first-child').clone()`

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('#list li').length; i++) {
  var newLi = $('#list li:first-child').clone();
  newLi.html(i+1)
  newLi.attr('rel', i+1);
  $('#newList').append(newLi);
}
```

Solution here:

https://jsfiddle.net/alvarojoao/dtxs4nxj/3/

Comment: @Nick please take a look in my answer, I updated the solution in the most `easy to adapt` process.

Comment: Why clone the first child each time, instead of cloning each child in the original list?

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration, your code is replacing "#newList"'s contents with the entire cloned list, and setting the "rel" attribute last, so every cloned "li" is getting the same "rel" attribute applied.

Have you tried jQuery's iterator, each()?  I find it easier to read.

```
$("ul#list li").each(
function(i,v){
    $(v).clone().attr("rel",i.toString()).appendTo("ul#newList");
}
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5Lf2h6zL/1/

Comment: No need to call `.toString()`, it's done automatically when you put a number into an attribute. Otherwise, this is essentially the same as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < $('#list li').length; i++) {
    $('#list li').eq(i).clone().attr('rel', i).appendTo($('#newList'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation using `attr(function)`

```
$('#newList').append($('#list li').clone().attr('rel', function( i){
  return i;
}));
```